# Routing Error, undefined method `searchable' for #<Class......> with Sunspot Solr / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I have added Sunsport Solr to my Rails application. The model on which I want to search is throwing a `Routing Error` exception, complaining of an `undefined method 'searchable' for #<Class..........>`. I have followed a few different setup instruction sets which all provide the same information, which I have matched exactly. I can't seem to pinpoint the issue. Relevant snippets below.

```
#dwelling.rb
class Dwelling < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :street_address, :city, :state, :zip, :nickname

  searchable do
    text :nickname
  end
...
```

--

```
#dwellings_controller.rb
class DwellingsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :signed_in_user

  def index
    @search = Dwelling.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
    end
    @dwellings = @search.results
  end
```

--

```
#Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.6'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'sunspot_rails', '~> 1.3.0'


# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development do
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
gem 'sunspot_solr'
end
```

Sometimes if I refresh a few times a separate error regarding a `key?` method is throw. Full error below.

```
NoMethodError in DwellingsController#index

undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass
```

I am more than puzzled - any ideas?

Comment: This appears to be related to the startup scripts, and automatic class loading being skipped because the Solr package is already included.  I am getting this idea from this discussion: http://outoftime.lighthouseapp.com/projects/20339/tickets/164-undefined-method-searchable-in-rake-rails-23x However, it's a really old issue and I'd assume this particular one has already been fixed, and we're looking at something else.  Also, what server are you on?  I only seem to have this issue with Apache+Passenger, but not WEBrick.